# Dynamically change model/schema in Express Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server which takes api calls and points them to specific routes.

```
app.use('/api/data01', require('./routes/dataRoute01'))
app.use('/api/data02', require('./routes/dataRoute02'))
app.use('/api/data03', require('./routes/dataRoute03'))
```

Each route has methods in them that are all indentical except for the Model that they call.

So, `dataRoute01.js` has a method like this:

```
//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  Data01.create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

`dataRoute02.js` has a method like this:

```
//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  Data02.create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

Is it possible to combine the routes into one file and instead dynamically change the Model being called? Perhaps by passing a unique identifier into the request?

Perhaps something along the lines of the below
(added in a `source` which will be the source of the request. It could be a single digit. `1` for example.

Point all api calls to the same route.

```
app.use('/api/data01', require('./routes/dataRoute'))
app.use('/api/data02', require('./routes/dataRoute'))
app.use('/api/data03', require('./routes/dataRoute'))
```

Then in the route do something like:

```
//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const source = req.body.source
  const schema = 'Data0' + source
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  schema.create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

---

**EDIT:**
Created a new attempt based on the answers posted below.
Also added in the api call as I think it will assist in the question.

```
//api.js

  addData(source, body) {
    const url = '/data0' + source
    return service
      .post(url, body) //body here also contains the source
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(errHandler)
  },
```

```
//dataRoute.js

const express = require('express')
const Data01 = require('../models/Data01')
const Data02 = require('../models/Data02')
const Data03 = require('../models/Data03')

const router = express.Router()

//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  Data0[req.body.source]
    .create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

However the bracket notation used just before the `.create` seems to get ignored resulting in an error response like this:

```
API response {stack: "ReferenceError: Data0 is not defined↵    at router…r\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15", message: "Data0 is not defined"}
```

Comment: you could create a variable which is equals to the url endpoint and use that to dinamically call the model

Comment: Please add the source of Date01, Date02. I mean from where you are getting this objects

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by keeping all data in single file like this.

`data.js`

```
module.expoprts = {
  Data01: {}, //someObject or you can require another module here
  Data02: {}, //someObject or you can require another module here
  Data03: {}, //someObject or you can require another module here
  ...
}
```

Then rewrite your code like this

```
const Data = require('./data'); // assuming it is kept in same directory

//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const source = req.body.source
  const schema = 'Data0' + source
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  Date[schema].create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

Or if you have already kept all Data objects in one place you can use that

The key point here is just the index-based notation for accessing the object property.

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more details

## Update

You have updated the question with the data-schema thanks for that

Let me explain what you are doing wrong here

```
//dataRoute.js

const express = require('express')
const Data01 = require('../models/Data01')
const Data02 = require('../models/Data02')
const Data03 = require('../models/Data03')

const router = express.Router()

//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  Data0[req.body.source]
    .create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

Here you have three objects `Data01`, `Data02` and `Data03`.

And you are accessing it like this `Data0[...]` but you don't have any variable like `Data0`, that's why you are getting `"ReferenceError: Data0 is not defined"`.

So you can fix this by creating one common Data object which will have all your data sources like this

```
const express = require('express')
const Data01 = require('../models/Data01')
const Data02 = require('../models/Data02')
const Data03 = require('../models/Data03')

const Data = {Data01, Data02, Data03} // created one single container object to hold all data sources.

const router = express.Router()

//CREATE
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body
  // Access property based on source from Data container
  const schema = 'Data0' + source
  Data[schema]
    .create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

Comment: Edited the post based on the bracket notation used here. Unfortunately bracket notation doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please have a look, Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Schemas.js

```
const Schema01 = require('./Schema01');
const Schema02 = require('./Schema02');
const Schema03 = require('./Schema03');

modules.exports = {
  Data01, Data02, Data03
}
```

router.js

```
const Schemas = require('./Schemas');

router.post('/api/data/:schema', (req, res, next) => {
  let { name, details, content, timestamp } = req.body;
  Schemas[req.params.schema].create({ name, details, content, timestamp })
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

Comment: Edited the post based on the bracket notation used here. Unfortunately bracket notation doesn't seem to be working.